# How can I check for coding errors in all the HTML files from my site?

Tags: error, files

I'm working dad's website which is OK but very badly coded. There are many errors like missing opening and closing tags, more brackets than is needed etc.

I know in VS Code offers `CTRL + SHIFT + M` which shows me current errors in opened current file. The problem is, I have in directory over 600 files. Some files are OK, some files not.

Is there a way to highlight all files in directory with errors and all the errors within a file?

For formatting I use Prettier which give me some feedback because when there is a error it doesn't format the code but again I must work with current file and manually check it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any thing that will check html errors on all your pages on your devlopment machine.

1. **HTML** :  I would use an extension for the browser such as [HTML Validator for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/bocbjjpebcmehmadhaiefilfieahhcmo).  Go direct to the website, flick through the pages and run the validator.  This will find HTML errors for you.
2. **SEO** : The second part is to use a website to check all the pages, such as [ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/) for Search Engine compliance. It is free and you can either check your website right away or schedule it for nightly or weekly checks.  You do have to create an account and verify that its your website.

*I am not associated with either of the sites.  But I use them both myself.*

Answer (score 1):

You can go to this web address and enter your URL - https://validator.w3.org/ and it will generate a report for you.

You can also use a site like GTMetrix https://gtmetrix.com/ to check the overall wellness/efficiency of your site, and it will generate a report of things that could be optimized, if any.